# compiling code with opencv on macports

Tags: opencv, makefile

I have compiled code with opencv that was installed via macports. However, on running my makefile, I get

```
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_core.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_ml.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_video.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libopencv_flann.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
```

Does it mean that the libraries are all not linked? What can i do about this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are compiling your code for one architecture (probably x86_64 ie Intel 64 bit ) and you asked macports to be built with i386 architecture ie 32 bit

So yo need to alter one or the other.

1) Change your code - add -arch x86_64 to the options for gcc in the compile rule.

2) Uninstall macports and then reinstall and choose the required build_arch in the [macports.conf](http://guide.macports.org/chunked/internals.configuration-files.html) file and check universal_archs which should have defaulted to both.

Comment: Opps i think i know what's wrong. In my upper level common make file, there are these two lines: CFLAGS += -arch i386 -arch x86_64 LDFLAGS += -arch i386 -arch x86_64 I removed -arch i386 for both and it worked. Thanks!